# Почему элемент рвет верстку?

Tags: html, css, css3

Не могу понять, почему элемент `div` в котором находится стрелочка при ее отсутствии рвет верстку

[Пример без стрелочки](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLmXwg)

```css
.insert {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px 10px 6px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.filed_input {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 34px;
}

.arrow_label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
}

.arrow_label:before {}

.arrow_label.on:before {
  content: '▲';
}

.container_field_input {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filed_input div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filed_input">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="insert" onclick="toggleDrop(ge('_arraw_label'));" />
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
</div>
<div class="filed_list"></div>
```

А если задаю стрелочку в псевдо элементе `::before` то все норм

[Пример со стрелочкой](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGMbga)

```css
.insert {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px 10px 6px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.filed_input {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 34px;
}

.arrow_label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
}

.arrow_label:before {
  content: '▼';
}

.arrow_label.on:before {
  content: '▲';
}

.container_field_input {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filed_input div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filed_input">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="insert" onclick="toggleDrop(ge('_arraw_label'));" />
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_label" id="_arraw_label"></div>
</div>
<div class="filed_list"></div>
```

Посмотрел через `firebug` там почему то у `arrow_label` отступ, хотя я его не задавал.

Comment: Весь код должен быть **прямо в тексте вопроса** без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: Air добрый. . .

Comment: @andreymal, не добрый... Просто надо же как-нибудь вникать в вопрос... )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все потому, что у вас в блоке `filed_input` получается строчных 2 элемента, которые по умолчанию вертикально выровнены по `baseline`. Когда вы убираете значение `content`, т.е. стрелку из элемента `::before`, высота этого элемента становится равной нулю, уровень `baseline` смешается и вы видите то, что видите.

Что делать:

```
.arrow_label:before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не помогло. Отступ все так же остается и рвет верстку.

Comment: @Анатолий тогда видимо я не понимаю, что значит в вашей терминологии "рвет верстку". Добавил в ответ скриншот. У вас мой код работает не так?

Comment: Загвозка в другом теперь если убрать content: ""; и оставить только  vertical-align: top; то будет как на скриншоте "до". Полагаю мне просто нужно сделать верстку заново

Comment: Без свойства `content` у вас не будет элемента `::before`. А почему вам так принципиально обойтись без него? Верстаете под ie6? ) Может быть тогда так `.input {vertical-align: top;}`

Comment: с учетом ie6, скажем так. Попробую, спасибо.
Но если не будет свойства ::before почему тогда область элемента раздувается?

Comment: А `div class="arrow_label"` не в счет что ли?

Comment: Именно из-за этого раздувается?

Comment: @Анатолий не понимаю, что значит "раздувается". )

Comment: Да, неверно написал. Там у него просто появляется отступ внутри главного дива.

Comment: @Анатолий вот - https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/vvMJgr?editors=1100 , должно работать в ie6+ . Ну кроме `content` конечно...